# OSGI compatible artifact for jaxb2-basics?

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, osgi

I used this artifact to generate equals and hashcode to my JAXB generated Java files:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxb2-basics.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

The result works very well in non-OSGI environments.
However, the artifact that is created from my project is used with OSGI. It seems like this artifact is not OSGI compatible, so I reverted my work.

We are using org.apache.felix / maven-bundle-plugin to generate the needed OSGI meta files, but when I try to export the custom packages, it fails because the artifact being used is not OSGI ready.

Are there OSGI - ready artifacts for this? Or should I create one for myself?
Thanks!

Comment: What does this mean: "when I try to export the custom packages, it fails because the artifact being used is not OSGI ready"? What did you try to do, and how does it fail? What's the error message? What does OSGi-ready mean??

Comment: By  not "OSGi ready", do you mean you are missing a valid Manifest.MF with import/export statements?

Comment: Author here. Please feel free to send me a PR making it "OSGI-ready".

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/bundlor-documentation-1.1.1.RELEASE/docs/user-guide/htmlsingle/user-guide.html#quickstart.command.line

Comment: @MartinBaumgartner thanks, I'll check that